ImportError: DLL Load failed while importing QtWebEngineWidgets: Не найден указанный модуль
Я написал небольшое приложение на Python при помощи PyQt5 в среде PyCharm, в приложении используется элемент просмотра HTML-страниц QWebEngineView.
После этого я собрал приложение при помощи pyinstaller (использованная команда: pyinstaller --onefile main.py). При попытке запустить полученный exe-файл выдается: 
При запуске приложения в среде никаких проблем нет, все работает корректно. Если кто-то сталкивался, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.
